# Data appear to be '0' when insert into access using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

The problem I have is that when I insert data into the database the values are all 0.

My columns are StudentID, IntakeCode, FirstName, LastName, Contactnumber, emailaddress and unitID.

This is 1st form

```
    If txtunitid.Text <> "" And txttp.Text <> "" Then

        cmdInsert.CommandText = "INSERT INTO StudentAcc (StudentID, UnitID) VALUES ('" & txttp.Text & "', '" & txtunitid.Text & "');"
        cmdInsert.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdInsert.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery()

        cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Accommodation SET Status = True WHERE Unit_ID = " & txtunitid.Text & ";"
        cmdUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdUpdate.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
        obj.Show()
        MsgBox(txtunitid.Text & " " & "Record updated.")

        Me.Hide()
    Else
        MsgBox("Hello")
    End If
    cmdUpdate.Dispose()
```

This is 2nd form

```
    If intakecodetxt.Text <> "" And firstnametxt.Text <> "" And lastnametxt.Text <> "" And MaskedTextBox1.Text <> "" And emailtxt.Text <> "" And IsNumeric(firstnametxt.Text) = False And IsNumeric(lastnametxt.Text) = False Then
        cmdUpdate.CommandText = "UPDATE Students SET IntakeCode = '" & intakecodetxt.Text & "', FirstName = '" & firstnametxt.Text & "', LastName = '" & lastnametxt.Text & "', ContactNumber = '" & MaskedTextBox1.Text & "', Email_Address = '" & emailtxt.Text & "' WHERE StudentID = '" & studentidtxt.Text & "';"

        cmdUpdate.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        cmdUpdate.Connection = cnnOLEDB
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery()
        MsgBox(studentidtxt.Text & " " & "Record updated.")
    Else
        MsgBox("Please Enter Value")
    End If
    cmdInsert.Dispose()
```

Comment: Start by logging the values somewhere immediately before you send them them to the DB. This will tell you if they are actually non-zero values to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

In the first statement you seem to be attempting to wrap the StudentId and UnitId fields in quotes, indicating they are character values and in the second statement, you seem to be referencing UnitId as a numeric value. I suspect that it is a numeric field and the string you're passing it is being converted to a zero.